# Converting a string to a stream

Tags: f#, .net-core

I'm trying to convert a string into a bytestream so that I can read said stream. So what I'm doing is that I convert the string into a char array and the write each char/byte into a MemoryStream which I later wrap in a BinaryReader

The way I've tried to implement it is like this:

```
let readData (data:string) = 
    let ms = new MemoryStream()
    let bw = new BinaryWriter(ms)
    data.ToCharArray() |> Array.iter (fun x -> bw.Write((byte)x))
    let br = new BinaryReader(bw.BaseStream)
    readStream 0 br
```

I later try to read it like this

```
let rec readStream c (br:BinaryReader) =
    let bytes = br.ReadBytes 16
    printfn "Size read is: %i" bytes.Length
```

But my result is always 0 bytes read, and I've verified that the string is not 0 bytes obviously. And I've tried calling Flush on the MemoryStream.

Am I missing something fundamental or is the another more obvious way to do this?

Comment: It looks like you're using `(byte)` as a type cast like in C# but `byte` is actually a function, so you can write `byte x`. That type cast syntax doesn't exist in F# but what you have happens to be equivalent because parens in F# are effectively just for grouping.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a terribly inefficient way of producing a `MemoryStream`. Specifically for this kind of application, it has a constructor that takes a byte array:

```
let bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes data
let stream = MemoryStream( bytes )
```

But even *that* may be an overkill. You haven't described your ultimate goal, but from your code it kind of looks like you just want to convert a string to a byte array. If that is true, all you need is just `Encoding.GetBytes`:

```
let readData (data:string) = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes data
```

.

#### On casting

Also note that when you do `(byte)x`, you apparently expect this to be a "convert to byte" operation, as in C#, but it's not. The "casting" operation in F# is expressed differently (with operators `:>` and `:?>`), and it can only be used for sub/supertypes (i.e. inherited classes and interfaces). Doesn't apply to primitives. There is no such thing as casting primitive types in F#.

What you're actually doing is calling a *function* called `byte`. So the parentheses are not needed there, function arguments in F# are specified with a space, i.e. `byte x`.

This function does indeed convert a char to a byte, but it does so by just taking the first byte of the char (chars are two-byte things, did you know?) and throwing away the second byte. This works fine when your char is ASCII (second byte is zero anyway), but will lose data when it's not. Try converting to byte and then back to char:

```
let x = 'a'
let y = char (byte x)
> val y : char = 'a'  // This worked

let x = 'Г'
let y = char (byte x)
> val y : char = '\019'  // Oops
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I'm just starting to learn F# so thank for taking your time to explain things. What I'm trying to do is a simple hexdump program, which can take either a parameter as a value to print out as hex or read a file and print it's content. However TheQuickBrownFox in all honesty wrote the answer to my question.

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you care to accept it?

Comment: Sorry I just updated my answer with a reason as to why your answer isn't the accepted one. But you have my upvote :)

Comment: I don't see any reason in your question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant my comment here on your answer. My reasoning is that you definitely have helped me understand F# better, however the accepted answer correctly specifies what I should do to be able to read the data from the BinaryWriter wrapping a MemoryStream. Which is what my question is really about.

Comment: I showed you a better way to create a memory stream, and if you create it that way, you won't need to reset the position afterwards.

Comment: Agreed, though one could argue that TheQuickBrownFox's answer explained why I couldn't read from the MemoryStream, whilst your answer showed a more efficient way of creating a MemoryStream which when created like that doesn't need to be reset. Would you mind if I take this up in Meta?

Comment: If you like. I don't care too much about my answer being accepted, I just wanted to make sure you understood the difference. Ultimately it is your discretion to accept the answer you think is the most helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

After writing to the `MemoryStream`, it's position is at the end. You need to reset the position to the start to read it all. You could add this to the start of your `readStream` function

```
br.BaseStream.Position <- 0L
```

Comment: Hah, it never even occured to me that I should reset the position, it's so obvious now. Thank you!